# Override parent form label within child form symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

My parent form type has a field "title" with a generic label "Title".
Lets say I have five child forms and three of them need to change the label. How do I do that. I'm going crazy.

```
class ParentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'generics.title',
        ]);
    }
}

class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // I thought I could change the label of parent around here
        // without removing and adding it again

        $builder->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
            'label' => 'generics.description',
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ParentType::class;
    }
}
```

I don't want to solve this in twig.

What about adding a custom titleLabel option in the ParentType and setting in in the childs configureOptions() method?

Comment: What's your form code? How to you render it? On what condition do you decide what label should be used? Where do you  want to decide which label to use? You need to be more specific. Actually you should add enough code and information to let us reproduce your situation.

Comment: Not to be a nudge, but shouldn't it be: "class ChildType extends ParentType" if you're inheriting from it? Then inside your buildForm method you can call 'parent::buildForm($builder, $options);' . If you're not directly using the parent class, you can always just let the child class add the 'title'

Comment: Isn't this a bad practice to extend directly from ParentType. I thought i should use getParent() method.

@yceruto thanks for code style

Answer (score 0):

You could use "template method pattern".
Write the template method named *getTitle* in ParentType.
And Specify this method call as the label option.

```
protected function getTitle() 
{
    return 'generics.title'
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder->add('title', TextType::class, [
       'label' => $this->getTitle(),
   ]);
}
```

Derive ChildType from ParentType and write concrete *getTitle* in ChildType.

```
class ChildType extends ParentType {
    protected function getTitle() 
    {
      return 'concrete label';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
        'label' => 'generics.description',
        ]);
    }
}
```